# How to get access to nuspec file of a nuget package on official nuget server?

Tags: c#, deployment, continuous-integration, package, nuget

I have a nuget package hosted on official nuget server. I want to get access to its nuspec file.

If that's not possible, is there any way I can get access to Manifect object ?

I tried

```
IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");
            var package = repo.FindPackage("trackerenableddbcontext");

            string root = "c:\\";

            package.ExtractContents(new PhysicalFileSystem(root), "tempfolder");
```

but it only extract dll files in lib folder. Not the nuspec file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
        public Manifest ReadServerNuspecFile(PackageRetrieveOptions options)
        {
            IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");
            var package = repo.FindPackage(options.ProjectName);

            using (var pkgStream = package.GetStream())
            {
                var pkgReader = new PackageReader(pkgStream);
                var manifest = Manifest.ReadFrom(pkgReader.GetNuspec(), true);
                return manifest;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting below error. Pls help. 
_The type or namespace name 'PackageReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_